# Networkx graph with Python

Tags: python, networkx, plotly-python

Suppose you have a list of tuples such as the following:
[image]

The first element of each tuple represents the person ID and the second represents the skill ID. How can I visualize this data with networkx or any other library?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a bipartite graph with networkx:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

tuples = [(0, 170),
        (0, 165),
        (1, 165),
        (1, 170),
        (2, 150),
        (2, 170),
        (3, 150),
        (3, 165),
        (4, 170),
        (4, 150)]
left_nodes = [tup[0] for tup in tuples]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(tuples)
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(G, nodes= left_nodes)
node_colors = ["turquoise" if node in left_nodes else "pink" for node in G.nodes]
nx.draw(G,pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_color = node_colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use sankey diagrams like below:

```
import holoviews as hv
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as pex
import pandas as pd
  
tuples = [(0, 170),
        (0, 165),
        (1, 165),
        (1, 170),
        (2, 150),
        (2, 170),
        (3, 150),
        (3, 165),
        (4, 170),
        (4, 150)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tuples, columns =['id', 'skill'])
df = df.assign(v=pd.Series([1]*len(tuples)).values)

hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.Sankey(df, kdims=["id","skill"])
```

output:
[image]